# what is wrong to display if condition correctly?

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "John Doe"
}, {
  name: "jamal"
}, {
  name: "Badr"
}, {
  name: "mohsen"
}]

arr.forEach((val) => {
  firstLetter = val.name.split(" ")[0].split("")[0];
});

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (firstLetter == "J" || firstLetter == "j") {
    console.log("Goodbye " + arr[i].name);
  } else {
    console.log("Hello " + arr[i].name);
  };
};
```

Comment: I think you did not post all of the code, and I dont understand your question so could you try to explain your problem

Comment: `firstLetter = val.name.split(" ")[0].split("")[0];` is going to replace the variable on every iteration. It does not magically remember each first letter. You should be read the first letter inside of your for loop.

Comment: i want dispaly if the first name's first letter is J or j console could display goodbye name whose first name is J or j but any letter else it could display hello + name

Comment: After the `forEach` loop, `firstletter` is the result for the last element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `firstLetter` has only the last value in it `m` as you're overwriting its value.
Change the code to:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "John Doe"
}, {
  name: "jamal"
}, {
  name: "Badr"
}, {
  name: "mohsen"
}]

const firstLetter = [];
arr.forEach((val) => {
  firstLetter.push(val.name.split(" ")[0].split("")[0]);
});

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (firstLetter[i] === "J" || firstLetter[i] === "j") {
    console.log("Goodbye " + arr[i].name);
  } else {
    console.log("Hello " + arr[i].name);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to say "Goodbye " + `val.name` for names which start with `J` or `j` (and "Hello " + `val.name` for others). There's no need to do two loops for this (do the `forEach` or the `for` loop).

In any case, you can address the first character in the name as `.name[0]` and use comparison operators or String methods to determine if the name starts with a `J` or a `j`.

See the following code snippet for an example of this.

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "John Doe"
}, {
  name: "jamal"
}, {
  name: "Badr"
}, {
  name: "mohsen"
}];

arr.forEach((val) => {
  if (val.name[0] === "J" || val.name[0] === "j") {
    console.log("Goodbye " + val.name);
  } else {
    console.log("Hello " + val.name);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an other loop after forEach, what you need is to check if the specific name starts with J/j

```
var arr = [{
            name: "John Doe"
        }, {
            name: "jamal"
        }, {
            name: "Badr"
        }, {
            name: "mohsen"
        }]
    
        arr.forEach((val) => {
            firstLetter = val.name.split(" ")[0].split("")[0];
    
            if (firstLetter == "J" || firstLetter == "j") {
                console.log("Goodbye " + val.name);
            } else {
                console.log("Hello " + val.name);
            };
    
        });
```